# Boost serialization “read access violation” when outputting to file via ofstream

Tags: c++, file, serialization, boost

I apologize in advance for the bit of code dumping here.

I have a pretty simple `Player` class in a game I'm creating. After the user enters a user name, I go into a save directory that should hold all player save files. If the file cannot be found, the program is supposed to create a new player object to use for the rest of the game.

Right after this new object is instantiated, I want to create a new save file for this new player. Creating the file with `std::ofstream` works just fine. The problem comes about when I'm trying to serialize the player class to that file. Specifically, my system throws a "read access violation" when using the overloaded `<<` operator from `boost::archive::text_oarchive`.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```cpp
// Inside the main function
Player player;
const auto player_name = login_menu.get_value();
const auto sav_dir = fs::current_path() / "sav";
bool player_exists = Player::exists(player_name, sav_dir);
if (player_exists)
{
    cons::File player_file(sav_dir / (player_name + ".dat"),
        cons::fopenmode::input);
    if (player_file.get_ifstream().is_open())
    {
        boost::archive::text_iarchive
            player_file_archive(player_file.get_ifstream());

        player_file_archive >> player;
    }
    else
    {
        cons::print(
            "",
            "ERROR: Save file was located, but cannot be loaded.",
            "It may be corrupted. Deleting save file."
        );
        cons::pause();
        player_file.delete_file();
        player_exists = false;
    }
}
if (!player_exists) // No player found; make new player
{
    player = Player(player_name, 1, 0, 1.0f);
    std::ofstream player_file(sav_dir / (player_name + ".dat"));

    if (!player_file.is_open()) // TODO Remove me
        cons::print("ERROR: OFSTREAM NOT OPENED");

    { // Create new save file
        boost::archive::text_oarchive 
            player_file_archive(player_file);

        player_file_archive << player; // TODO FIXME Throwing read access violation
    }
}
```

For additional help, here is the Player class (without implementation):

```cpp
class Player
{
public:
    Player();
    Player(std::string name, unsigned short level, int money, float stealth);

    // ... Getter and setters ...

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    std::string name_;
    unsigned short level_;
    int money_;
    float stealth_;

    template <class Archive>
    /**
     Used for Boost library data serialization

     @param ar      Archive reference
     @param version Unused variable needed for Boost compatibility
    */
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned version)
    {
        ar & name_;
        ar & level_;
        ar & money_;
        ar & stealth_;
    }

public:
    /**
     Searches for a player's save file in a directory

     @param player_name The name of the player
     @param save_dir    The directory to search for the player's save file
     @returns 'true' if the player's save file is found; 'false' otherwise
    */
    static bool exists(const std::string& player_name, 
        const std::filesystem::path& save_dir);
};
```

If anyone knows how to fix my issue, it would be much appreciated. Here is some console log of the exception:

```
'Ditacker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Dev\C++\Games\Console Games\Ditacker\Ditacker\bin\Debug-x64\Ditacker.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'Ditacker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Ditacker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Ditacker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\AVG\Antivirus\aswhook.dll'. 
'Ditacker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Ditacker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Dev\C++\Games\Console Games\Ditacker\Ditacker\bin\Debug-x64\boost_serialization-vc142-mt-gd-x64-1_72.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Ditacker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Ditacker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Ditacker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vcruntime140_1d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Ditacker.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbased.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x1e910 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: read access violation.
**_Pg** was 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

The program '[121404] Ditacker.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. - The `cons` namespace contains various console IO functions. The ones used here should be self-explanatory, but I can provide more information on them if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce it with the following code (which is just your code made to compile, and adding some style changes/output).

If you still have "the crash" then it must originate from somewhere else. Likely, the player object is stale (are you actually passing it by reference or pointer in your code?).

You can use Asan/UBSan to locate errors like these. Also, valgrind.

Otherwise, post a self contained program that exhibits the crash.

### DEMO TIME

See here a live demo that exercises the happy and error paths:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d34342182684203c)**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

class Player {
  public:
    Player() = default;
    Player(std::string name, unsigned short level, int money, float stealth)
            : name_(std::move(name)), level_(level), money_(money),
              stealth_(stealth) {}

    // ... Getter and setters ...

  private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Player const& player) {
        return os << "Player {" << std::quoted(player.name_)
                  << ", level:" << player.level_ << ", money:" << player.money_
                  << ", stealth:" << player.stealth_ << " }";
    }

    std::string name_;
    unsigned short level_;
    int money_;
    float stealth_;

    template <class Archive>
    /**
     Used for Boost library data serialization

     @param ar      Archive reference
     @param version Unused variable needed for Boost compatibility
    */
    void serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned /*unused*/) {
        ar& name_& level_& money_& stealth_;
    }

  public:
    /**
     Searches for a player's save file in a directory

     @param player_name The name of the player
     @param save_dir    The directory to search for the player's save file
     @returns 'true' if the player's save file is found; 'false' otherwise
    */
    static bool exists(const std::string& player_name,
                       const std::filesystem::path& save_dir) {
        return fs::exists((save_dir / player_name).replace_extension(".dat"));
    }
};

struct {
    static std::string get_value() { return "player_name"; }
} static login_menu;

namespace cons {
    namespace fopenmode {
        static auto const input = std::ios::in;
    }
    struct File {
        std::string fname;
        std::ifstream ifs;
        File(std::string fname, std::ios::openmode mode)
                : fname(fname), ifs(fname, mode) {
            ifs.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);
        }
        auto& get_ifstream() { return ifs; }
        bool delete_file() {
            if (ifs.is_open()) {
                ifs.close();
            }
            return fs::remove(fname);
        }
    };
    template <typename... T> void print(T const&... v) {
        for (auto&& frag : { boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(v)... }) {
            std::cout << frag << std::endl;
        }
    }
    void pause() {
        std::cout << "(press Enter to continue)\n";
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
} // namespace cons

int main() {
    // Inside the main function
    const auto player_name = login_menu.get_value();
    auto const sav_dir = fs::current_path() / "sav";
    fs::create_directories(sav_dir);
    auto const fname = (sav_dir / player_name).replace_extension(".dat");

    if (Player::exists(player_name, sav_dir)) {
        std::cout << "Opening existing file " << fname << "\n";
        cons::File player_file(fname, cons::fopenmode::input);

        try {
            boost::archive::text_iarchive player_file_archive(
                player_file.get_ifstream());

            Player player;
            player_file_archive >> player;

            std::cout << "Player: " << player << "\n";
        } catch (std::exception const& e) {
            cons::print(e.what(),
                        "ERROR: Save file was located, but cannot be loaded.",
                        "It may be corrupted. Deleting save file.");
            cons::pause();
            player_file.delete_file();
        }
    }

    if (!Player::exists(player_name, sav_dir))
    { // No player found; make new player
        std::cout << "Creating save file " << fname << "\n";
        Player player(player_name, 1, 0, 1.0f);
        std::ofstream player_file(fname);

        { // Create new save file
            boost::archive::text_oarchive player_file_archive(player_file);
            player_file_archive << player;
        }
    }
}
```

Executing

```sh
g++ -std=c++17 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lboost_serialization -o test.exe
(./test.exe; ./test.exe; sed -i 's/serializa/corrup/' sav/*; ./test.exe; ./test.exe) < /dev/null
head sav/*
```

Prints

```
Creating save file "/tmp/1587589055-765971644/sav/player_name.dat"
Opening existing file "/tmp/1587589055-765971644/sav/player_name.dat"
Player: Player {"player_name", level:1, money:0, stealth:1 }
Opening existing file "/tmp/1587589055-765971644/sav/player_name.dat"
invalid signature
ERROR: Save file was located, but cannot be loaded.
It may be corrupted. Deleting save file.
(press Enter to continue)
Creating save file "/tmp/1587589055-765971644/sav/player_name.dat"
Opening existing file "/tmp/1587589055-765971644/sav/player_name.dat"
Player: Player {"player_name", level:1, money:0, stealth:1 }
22 serialization::archive 17 0 0 11 player_name 1 0 1.000000000e+00
```